# SubSelect with before Results (multiple rows)

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, union

I have already searched about my problem, but I havn't find anything suitable.
What approach could bring be to the final result ?

Initial position: (DATABASE USED: DB2)

Query with `UNION`, example:

```
SELECT 'HEAD', state, ID, Name, Country, '0'
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE state= '1'
UNION
SELECT 'POS', state, '0', '0', '0', Item
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE state= '1'
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| TYPE | STATE | ID  | Name | Country | Item |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| HEAD | 1     | 999 | Test | PL      | 0    |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 1     | 0   | 0    | 0       | ABC  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 1     | 0   | 0    | 0       | DEF  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 1     | 0   | 0    | 0       | GHI  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
```

so "state = '1'" is fixed

I want to do that union select dynamic based on the resultes a pre-query gives like:

Query:

```
SELECT state
FROM TABLE_C
```

Result:

```
+-------+
| state |
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
| 2     |
+-------+
| 3     |
+-------+
```

the final result should be:

```
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| TYPE | STATE | ID  | Name | Country | Item |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| HEAD | 1     | 999 | Test | PL      | 0    |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 1     | 0   | 0    | 0       | ABC  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 1     | 0   | 0    | 0       | DEF  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 1     | 0   | 0    | 0       | GHI  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| HEAD | 2     | 888 | Test2| DE      | 0    |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 2     | 0   | 0    | 0       | XXX  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 2     | 0   | 0    | 0       | YYY  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 2     | 0   | 0    | 0       | GGG  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| HEAD | 3     | 555 | Test7| DE      | 0    |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 3     | 0   | 0    | 0       | TTT  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 3     | 0   | 0    | 0       | SSS  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
| POS  | 3     | 0   | 0    | 0       | AAA  |
+------+-------+-----+------+---------+------+
```

Comment: Does your `TABLE_C` has any relationship with `TABLE_A` ?

Comment: Substitute `WHERE state= '1'` with `WHERE state in (SELECT state
FROM TABLE_C)`

Comment: Thank you @Giorgos Betsos, sometimes the solution is easier than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not quite clear form your question what it is that you exactly want...    hope this is what you need...

```
SELECT 'HEAD', state, ID, Name, Country, '0'
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE state in (SELECT state FROM TABLE_C)
UNION
SELECT 'POS', state, '0', '0', '0', Item
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE state in (SELECT state FROM TABLE_C)
```